# STM32F103 Cannot receive data via UART on RX interrupt

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, modbus

I try to make STM32F103 communicate with Eastron SDM630 smart meter via Modbus.

On the hardware side I have chinese BluePill board with STM32F103C8T6. USART1 is used for serial comms with smart meter using the chinese TTL-RS485 converter module. The signals are 5V but STM32 USART1 is mapped to pins PA9, PA10 that are 5V tolerant. PA8 is used as the DE/RE control pin (enables RS485 transmission whel set to high level). Baudrate is 9600. USART3 is used for debug with USB-serial dongle.

The problem is that data is being transferred OK and smart meter gets it right and responds correctly (checked it with logic analyzer) but STM32 cannot receive the response. I use RXNE interrupt on USART1 but it looks like the ISR never get fired.

Logic analyzer results:
[image: Logic analyzer results]

The code assumes that I send a Modbus "Read input register" command and wait for 9-byte response (1byte for slaveID, 1byte for command code, 1byte for data response size, 4bytes of response and 2bytes of CRC16 checksum).

**main.c**

```
#include "main.h"
#include "gpio.h"
#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include <string.h>
#include "crc16.h"
#include "word.h"

uint8_t buffer[256];
uint8_t cmd[256];
uint8_t cmdCounter = 0;
volatile uint8_t response[255];
volatile uint8_t responseCounter = 0;
volatile uint8_t rxComplete = 0;
uint8_t estimatedCounter = 0;
uint16_t crc = 0xFFFF;


void SystemClock_Config(void);
void CycleComplete(void);
void SerialPrint(UART_HandleTypeDef *usart, uint8_t *buffer, int n);.
void RXCallback(void);


void SerialPrint(UART_HandleTypeDef *usart, uint8_t *buffer, int n)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(usart, (uint8_t *)buffer, n, 100);
}

void RXCallback()
{
    response[responseCounter] = (uint8_t)(USART1->DR & 0x00FF);
    if(responseCounter == estimatedCounter)
    {
        CycleComplete();
    }
    else
    {
        __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_RXNE);
        responseCounter++;
    }
}

void CycleComplete()
{
    int n;
    n = sprintf((char*)buffer, "Received %d bytes\n", responseCounter);
    SerialPrint(&huart3, buffer, n);

    n = sprintf((char*)buffer, "Response: 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x, 0x%02x\n", response[0], response[1], response[2], response[3], response[4], response[5], response[6], response[7], response[8]);
    SerialPrint(&huart3, buffer, n);

    crc = 0xFFFF;
    rxComplete = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();

    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    MX_USART3_UART_Init();

    int n = sprintf((char *)buffer, "Starting up...\n");
    SerialPrint(&huart3, buffer, n);

    while (1)
    {
        cmdCounter = 0;
        cmd[0] = 0x01;
        cmd[1] = 0x04;
        cmd[2] = 0x00;
        cmd[3] = 0x00;
        cmd[4] = 0x00;
        cmd[5] = 0x02;
        for(int a = 0; a <= 5; a++)
        {
            crc = crc16_update(crc, cmd[a]);
        }
        cmd[6] = lowByte(crc);
        cmd[7] = highByte(crc);

        estimatedCounter = 9; // slaveID + opCode + no.of bytes + 4 bytes of data + 2 bytes of CRC16

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        SerialPrint(&huart1, cmd, 8);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

        while(rxComplete != 1){};
        rxComplete = 0;

        HAL_Delay(3000);
    }
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI_DIV2;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL4;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }

    HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq() / 1000);
    HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}
```

**stm32f1xx_it.c**

```
#include "stm32f1xx_it.h"
#include "stm32f1xx.h"
#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"
#include "main.h"

extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

void NMI_Handler(void)
{
}

void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
    }
}

void MemManage_Handler(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
    }
}

void BusFault_Handler(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
    }
}

void UsageFault_Handler(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
    }
}

void SVC_Handler(void)
{
}

void DebugMon_Handler(void)
{
}

void PendSV_Handler(void)
{
}

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    HAL_IncTick();
    HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();
}


void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 0 */
    if(__HAL_UART_GET_IT_SOURCE(&huart1, UART_IT_RXNE) != RESET)
    {
        RXCallback();
    }
    HAL_NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
    /* USER CODE END USART1_IRQn 0 */
    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_IRQn 1 */

    /* USER CODE END USART1_IRQn 1 */
}
```

**usart.c**

```
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{
    huart1.Instance = USART1;
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
}

void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
{
    huart3.Instance = USART3;
    huart3.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
    huart3.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart3.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart3.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart3.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart3.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart3.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
    {
        _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef *uartHandle)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    if (uartHandle->Instance == USART1)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();

        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 0, 0);
        HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
    }
    else if (uartHandle->Instance == USART3)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_USART3_CLK_ENABLE();

        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    }
}

void HAL_UART_MspDeInit(UART_HandleTypeDef *uartHandle)
{
    if (uartHandle->Instance == USART1)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_DISABLE();

        HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_9 | GPIO_PIN_10);

        HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
    }
    else if (uartHandle->Instance == USART3)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_USART3_CLK_DISABLE();
        HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10 | GPIO_PIN_11);
    }
}
```

**gpio.c**

```
#include "gpio.h"

void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

    /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    /*Configure GPIO pin : PC13 */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /*Configure GPIO pin : PA8 */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
```

The code is generated with CubeMX. Some comment blocks (but NOT code!) are deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can determine, the only place you explicitly enable `UART_IT_RXNE` is in `RxCallback()` which in turn is only ever called from `USART1_IRQHandler()`.

Quite simply the interrupt is never enabled.

Comment: Right. It's working now. Thank you. For those who will work on such problems: there are numerous UART RX interrupt examples for STM32 on Web but no mention that you must re-enable interrupt after every received portion of data.

Comment: @X16 Are you sure you must re-enable the interrupt and not just clear a flag? Btw you might want to look into DMA for this, since lots of STM32 apparently support it and it offloads the receiving MCU nicely.

Comment: @Lundin : That didn’t sound right to me either (because it is not necessary), but not knowing what all that CubeMX and HAL cruft was doing, decided to let it lie.  If anything it is a new question, rather than a discussion of this answer.